# Assign result of find command to a list variable in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a base directory with a set of subdirs inside, some of those dirs have files with extension of jpg. I want to copy those files to another dir, this is my objective.
I decided to assign the value of find to a list variable and then iterate over the list and copy the source file to target destination.

```
mylist=$(find . -type f -name "*.png")
```

As you can tell the mylist var will have only one element. It will be string containing all the different files found, and there are a lot of files inside the index 0.

I have tried to use the following method to separate the lines on by one onto a new array

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    files+=( "$line" )
done <"$mylist"
```

However this did not work and just dumps all the lines from the result of the find.

I am using bash 3.2 in MacOS.I would like to know how can I parse the $mylist var so that I could have another variable with a file path in each index. Or as an alternative to make the result of the find command into a list right after the execution

Answer (score 7):

**If the filenames are guaranteed to contain no white spaces**, the following should suffice to store all the names in an array variable

```
mylist=($(find . -type f -name "*.png"))
```

Then you can access individual filenames by `${mylist[0]}`, `${mylist[1]}`,  `${mylist[2]}`, and so on.